# javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

(I didn't find proper answer from the existing questions that's why I posted this)

I have an application which processes quite big number of data. I am getting the below errors / exceptions and the process gets terminated. **But increasing the ram size resolving the issue.** (but we can't do it for some restriction)

2019-02-11 14:02:59,662 ERROR [net.xxx.RuleHandler] (Thread-185232 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1521150484)) failed to get rules from db: org.hibernate.HibernateException: **Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!**

at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl.processAnyDelayedAfterCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorTrackingImpl.java:105) [hibernate-core-4.2.27.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.27.Final-redhat-1]

2019-02-11 14:02:59,693 ERROR [net.xxx.**ejb.SearchReqMDB**] (Thread-185232 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1521150484)) Something failed while search indexing: net.xxx.xxx.JMPException: **javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back**

How to resolve this issue? Do I need to increase the timeout value for ejb call? and if yes then where I need to change it.

Using JBOSS 6 EAP , EJB & JPA

Comment: can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @SuryaN I see the JMS messaging and global transaction here Try to figure out which exception leads to the transaction rollback.